# Eclipse Rhostudio not showing error messages

Tags: eclipse, syntax-error, rhomobile, error-logging

I have just started using the rhostudio plugin for eclipse 3.7.2 on Windows.

I have erroneous code but the console never seems to output error messages.

When I launch the simulator I do get some logs but as soon as it hits a bad line of code it stops logging and the simulator window goes blank.

Can anybody help?

Comment: ended up upgrading to a new version of rhostudio helped me solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can increase the amount of log output by changing the log level in:

```
rhoconfig.txt
```

in your projects root folder and setting MinSeverity as follows:

```
# Rhodes log properties
# log level
# 0-trace, 1-info(app level), 3-warnings, 4-errors
# for production set to 3
MinSeverity  = 0

# enable copy log messages to standard output, useful for debugging
LogToOutput = 1
```